# Capture Text Values From An HTML Element

Tags: javascript, html, video, jmeter

My site contains a video (video is of a static image). It requires the user to just click and play it.

I wanted to create a script in JMeter, and after recording I saw ...

- dynamic time stamp(1601912284332),
- sessionId(like this "c8cd4be84b74b7c2975ece1d"),
- bandwidth etc...

As shown in code below:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
       #EXTM3U #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=513000,RESOLUTION=480x270 https://secure.brightcove.com/services/mobile/streaming/index/rendition.m3u8?assetId=6177603809001&amp;secure=true&amp;pubId=2421677124001&amp;videoId=6177599447001 #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=795000,RESOLUTION=640x360 https://secure.brightcove.com/services/mobile/streaming/index/rendition.m3u8?assetId=6177605145001&amp;secure=true&amp;pubId=2421677124001&amp;videoId=6177599447001 #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=995000,RESOLUTION=640x360 https://secure.brightcove.com/services/mobile/streaming/index/rendition.m3u8?assetId=6177601971001&amp;secure=true&amp;pubId=2421677124001&amp;videoId=6177599447001 #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1295000,RESOLUTION=960x540 https://secure.brightcove.com/services/mobile/streaming/index/rendition.m3u8?assetId=6177603812001&amp;secure=true&amp;pubId=2421677124001&amp;videoId=6177599447001 #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1826000,RESOLUTION=960x540 https://secure.brightcove.com/services/mobile/streaming/index/rendition.m3u8?assetId=6177599739001&amp;secure=true&amp;pubId=2421677124001&amp;videoId=6177599447001 #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=2126000,RESOLUTION=1280x720 https://secure.brightcove.com/services/mobile/streaming/index/rendition.m3u8?assetId=6177601975001&amp;secure=true&amp;pubId=2421677124001&amp;videoId=6177599447001 
</body>
</html>
```

Can anybody help in as in how may I proceed with capturing these values?

Comment: You need to research `extract text from HMTL element`. One example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56050076/how-to-extract-content-from-p-html-tag

Comment: I don't think the question is about extracting text, but parsing a string to split out the values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the [M3U8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U) playlist for the desired video aspect ratio (or use the random one) via [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) and once you have it stored into a JMeter Variable you can "feed" this variable to the [HLS Plugin](https://github.com/Blazemeter/HLSPlugin) (can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager)](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

The HLS plugin will do all the "magic" for you like parse the playlist, get video/audio streams and download them like a real user in a real browser.

More information: [JMeter HLS Plugin 3.0 is out!](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/HLS-3.0-Release)